# PG::UndefinedColumn, Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-admin

Rails rookie here.  Horrendous understanding of the backend. But trying. When I attempt to edit a product in my admin section (rails_admin), I get the following error message:

**"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /product/1/edit
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column line_items.product_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE "line_items"....
                                                       ^
: SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE "line_items"."product_id" = $1 "**

I dropped my db the other day in a tragic bout of noob confusion and am assuming this is a consequence of the rebuild. I am not sure what code is relevant enough to paste, please let me know if I can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a migration to add `product_id` to your `line_items` table?

Comment: That did it. I love you guys. @muistooshort , if you put this in an answer box I think I can give you the "points".